# insert into select with different data types

Tags: sql, libreoffice-base

I am trying to copy data from `table1` to `table2` in libreoffice base using a query like:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
FROM "table2";
```

`column4` is a `VARCHAR` with value like `'5/5/2015'`. My problem is that `column2` is a `DATE` type. So how can I cast `column4` as `DATE` to be registred in `column2`?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]. Hint: Have you tried looking for conversion functions in your database documentation?

Comment: i'm find something like this SELECT CAST("5-5-2015", DATE) but when i replace "5-5-2015" by my column name that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to use the CAST command.

It looks like you are converting the string "column4" into a date NOT the data in the column.  Try replacing the quotes with brackets like this...

```
INSERT INTO table1 ([column1], [column2], ...)
SELECT [column3], CAST([column4] AS DATE), ...
FROM table2;
```

or drop all the delimiters like this...

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2, ...)
SELECT column3, CAST(column4 AS DATE), ...
FROM table2;
```

You only need to enclose column names if they have spaces / special characters or include SQL keywords

Comment: i tried what you suggested but it does not work. i think that it is necessary to enclosing all column names. And my column names have spaces.

Comment: If your column names have spaces then yes you need to enclose them.  If it's still not working please post the whole query along with the error message.

Comment: here is my querry: INSERT INTO "personne" ("numsecu", "nom", "datenaissance")
SELECT "Num Securité Sociale", "Nom", CAST[Date de naissance] FROM "donnee"